# Problem with IN Clause in soql

Tags: soql, delete, campaign-member, after

Hi everyone I'm having a problem with a query over campaignmember object, Im trying to use In clause to filter by id , but it retrieves nothing, crazy thing is that the list actually has an id, and it belongs to a campaignmember record. This is my code, this method is being called from after delete

```
public void doNotAllowDeleteCampaignMembers(Map<ID,CampaignMember> oldMapCampaignMembers){
        String usrProfileName = [select u.Profile.Name from User u where u.id = :Userinfo.getUserId()].Profile.Name;
        system.debug('oldMapCampaignMembers.keyset():'+oldMapCampaignMembers.keyset());        
        for(campaignmember cmp:[SELECT Id, Campaign.RecordType.Name FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id IN :oldMapCampaignMembers.keyset() ]){
            system.debug('mCmRec.get(cm.id).Campaign.RecordType.Name:'+cmp.Campaign.RecordType.Name);
            //it never gets here since In clause its not detecting the id  
        }
}
```

Any ideas of what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way you have tagged your message it seems to me that you are running that code in an `after delete` trigger context. If the Ids you are using are the ones that are deleted, they are no longer available for query on the `after` part of the trigger. (They are supposed to count as deleted, hence they are no longer returned by the SOQL Query)